# E:The package astah-uml needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, updates

guys

I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I got this error when I update my system :

**E:The package astah-uml needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.**

This error prevent me from installing other packages

How can I solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: That package is not in the Ubuntu repositories. So ask yourself: Why did I install it? Where did I get it from? Then go back to that source for a fresh copy of the package.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .deb file for installing a free, fully functional trial version of Astah UML on Debian-based operating systems at the official [Astah website](https://astah.net/downloads/). To continue to use Astah UML after the trial period has expired you must purchase the software. That's possibly why you got a `The package astah-uml needs to be reinstalled` error message. If you don't want to buy the software, then uninstalling astah-uml with `sudo apt remove astah-uml` will stop the error message from reappearing.

If you get the same error about needing to reinstall astah-uml when trying to uninstall astah-uml with `sudo apt remove astah-uml`, then running `sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove astah-uml` fixes it.

Comment: When I type "sudo apt remove astah-uml", I get the same error about needing to reinstall astah-uml. Anything else I can try? E: "sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove astah-uml" fixed it.